# JQuery Text Editor - adding additional dropdown list in the toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've implemented the JQueryTE in my application. Along with the usual tools that JQueryTE has to offer, I'd like to include a drop down picker with a list of  predefined fields acting like placeholders, such as [[Title]],[[FirstName]] etc. I know its possible with CKEditor using placeholder plugin but can it be done with JQueryTE?

The most obvious method I would have thought was to try and add/append a option menu to the toolbar which will fire off some code which adds the field name, but not having much luck.

Can someone have a look at my jsfiddle please?
    `jsfiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/jalz/hou94u8a/2/

```
$('.jqte-primary').jqte( 
            { 
                title: true,
                format: true,
                fsize: true,
                color: true,                    
                b: true,
                i: true,
                u: true,
                ol: true,
                ul: true,
                sub: true,
                sup: true,
                outdent: true,
                indent: true,
                left: true,
                center: true,
                right: true,
                strike: true,
                link: true,
                unlink: true,
                remove: true,
                rule: true,
                source: false           
            } 
        );
$( ".jqte_toolbar" ).append( "<span style=\"margin-left: 12px; padding-top: 6px; vertical-align: middle;\"><a href=\"\" class=\"save_link\">Save</a></span>" );


/* this is the one that does not work - this control does not display in JQueryTE and then figure out how to fire the value chosen in the appropriate place */
selectValues = { "1": "test 1", "2": "test 2" };

$.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
$('.jqte_toolbar').append($("<option/>", {
    value: key,
    text: value
}));
});


$( ".jqte_toolbar" ).append( "<span style=\"margin-left: 12px; padding-top: 6px; vertical-align: middle;\"><a href=\"\" class=\"field_list\">End</a></span>" );


$(".field_list").click( function () {

        /* Insert the value into */
alert('insert value');

    } )
```

Many thanks

Comment: please add your code to this post.

Comment: added code, think its because I'm trying to add a form element to the top of the toolbar, however don't know how to do it otherwise?

Comment: Nevermind, I decided to use TinyMCE which is hosted externally to my application but has this feature built in.

Answer (score 0):

hoping this helps to anybody that need to do something like this. I was using JQTE v 1.4 and JQuery 3.4 with JQuery-ui 1.12. What I did was to mimic the text format combo box that already have the desired behavior.

In this example the list is dynamically populated from an AJAX call which is the reason why I use dynamic element's Ids; on top of that I needed to place the same combo box with different content once on each depending on a parameter because there are many jqte's dynamically added to my page. Given that scenario the main entrance:

```
$("div[id^=\"jqteContainer_\"]").each(function(){
  let currParamId = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1]; //Obtain the id which have the param to know which combo belongs to which jqte toolbar
  let currentCombo = $(this);
  $.ajax("getData.[php/jsp/asp/aspx]",{ // The AJAX call to get the information for the options
    data: { id: currParamId  },
    success: function(dataResponse){
      let data = dataResponse.data; //Assuming data is an array with the information
      let newOptions = "";
      for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){ //Mimicking the HTML and CSS of jqte format combo box for each option
        newOptions += "<a class=\"jqte_format jqte_format_0 unselectable optMyClass\" data-myid=\"" + data[i].myId + "\" data-otherid=\"" + data[i].otherId + "\" role=\"menuitem\" unselectable=\"on\" style=\"user-select: none;\">" + data[i].name + "</a>";
      }
 // Mimicking the HTML and CSS of the combo box container as jqte format combo box container
      currentCombo.children("div.jqte").children("div.jqte_toolbar").append("<div class=\"jqte_tool jqte_tool_1 unselectable\" role=\"button\" style=\"user-select: none;width:15%\" unselectable=\"on\"><a id=\"myCustomCombo_" + currParamId + "\" data-myid=\"" + currParamId +"\" class=\"jqte_tool_label unselectable myCustomCombo\" unselectable=\"on\" style=\"user-select: none;width:95%\"><span class=\"jqte_tool_text unselectable nowrap\" unselectable=\"on\" style=\"user-select: none;\">My Combo Label</span><span class=\"jqte_tool_icon unselectable\" unselectable=\"on\" style=\"user-select: none;\"></span></a><div id=\"myComboOptions_" + currParamId + "\" class=\"jqte_formats unselectable\" unselectable=\"on\" style=\"user-select: none; display: none;\">" + newOptions + "</div></div>");
    },
    error: showResult,
    method: "POST"
  });
});

$("body").on("click", ".myCustomCombo", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#myComboOptions_"+$(this).attr("data-myid")).css("display","block");
});

$("body").on("click", ".optMyClass", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Your code per option. you can use the data-xxxx to differentiate
});
```

First of all, I had to add the combo box in each jqte in the page. In my case I have many jqte-s. However, this can be avoided just setting your Id if you have only one.

Next is mimicking jqte's format combo box used to list the text formats. The first part is adding the options, which are a bunch of anchors (a tags) with the information needed for your code in order to differentiate each one and the combo box if needed. In this case, the options are from an AJAX call, but it can be replaced for any static HTML that mimics the HTML showed here.

After implementing our options they are added to the corresponding jqte's toolbar which is the grandchildren of the jqte container (usually a div as in my case where the jqte textarea is a direct child), and add the rest of the HTML and CSS mimicking jqte's format combo box. Pay attention in the custom class added here (.myCustomCombo) because it is the way to make the show/hide of the options.

Finally is the javascript code which is pretty straight forward. The first one is just to show the options of our dropdown combo box, the next one is to do whatever we need once the option is selected. Pay attention to the way it is done because using the usual $(".myCustomCombo").click(...) are not going to work due to the fact that the combo box is generated dynamically. If it is already in the page (statically defined) the usual way to define this event should work; the same applies for the options.

Hoping this example be useful. Have fun and a great day.